# How to place one element inside another in raphael js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

Im trying to create an interactive seating layout like this [Seats.io](http://www.seats.io/demos/chartdrawer). However I dont need the exact features but just few things such as:

1. Plotting seats anywhere on the screen
2. Plotting list of seats from one point to another
3. Seats hover as circle when plotting from one mouse click point to another

After much research in Jquery and simultaneously on [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/), I have decided to start working with raphaeljs. Im totally new to the vector graphics. So obviously there might be something that I may be missing. I have followed this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRtAq/9358/) to draw a straight line. I have also created another script to plot circles anywhere on the window(the circles will mean seats) following is the script

```
window.onload = function () {

var height = $(document).outerHeight(true);
var width = $(document).width();

var radius = 10;
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, width, height);
var i = 0;
$(document).click(function (e) {

    i = i + 1;
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var seat = paper.circle(x, y, radius)
            .attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#f00", opacity: .4})
            .data("i", i);

    seat.mouseover(function () {
        this.attr("opacity", 1);
    });
    seat.mouseout(function () {
        this.attr("opacity", .4);
    });
});
```

}

using the above script I'm able to plot circles(seats) on my screen. Now based on the fiddle example  lines are drawn using 'path', so is it possible to load circles on every path and draw them as sequential line of circles one after the other, or do I have to take any different approach.

Also on a side note is there any opensource project or code for the [Seats.io](http://www.seats.io/demos/chartdrawer)

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but would getPointAtLength help if you traverse down the line http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getPointAtLength placing a circle at certain steps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ben from [seats.io](http://seats.io) here.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getPointAtLength is indeed what we use. You'll basically need to

1. calculate a helper path between start and end point. You already have that.
2. calculate the distance between seats (based on seat size): `helperPath.getTotalLength() / (numberOfSeats - 1);`
3. for each seat, call `getPointAtLength` and draw a circle around that
   point: `helperPath.getPointAtLength(distanceBetweenSeatsOnHelperPath * i++)`

Obviously, it gets more interesting if you want to snap to a grid to align rows, curve rows, etc, but you should be able to get started with the above.

Comment: magic, pure magic. Plus keeping a bit of state on the side, of course ;)